# HQL get parent from child without child knowing parent

Tags: hibernate, hql, parent

I've the following problem: I want to retrieve the parent from a child via HQL.

**Parent.hbm.xml**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="Parent" table="Parent">
    <id name="uuid" type="java.lang.String" unsaved-value="null" access="field">
        <column name="uuid" not-null="true" />
        <generator class="org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator" />
    </id>

    <list name="events" table="ParentToChild" cascade="all-delete-orphan" lazy="false">
        <key column="parentUuid" />
        <index column="idx" />
        <one-to-many class="Child" />
    </list>

</class>

<query name="findParentByChild">
    <![CDATA[
         select p from Parent as p, Child as c where c.uuid = :uuid and p.uuid = c.parentUuid 
         ]]>
</query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Child.hbm.xml**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="Child" table="Child">

    <id name="uuid" type="java.lang.String" access="field">
        <column name="uuid" not-null="true" />
        <generator class="org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator" />
    </id>

    <other properties..>
    </class>
 </hibernate-mapping
```

I can see the table generated for the child contains the parentUuid column, so my question is how do I do this in HQL? Can I use the foreign key in the HQL?

Answer (score 2):

You can use join:

```
select p Parent from Parent p join p.events c where c.uuid = :uuid
```